# Need some TinyMCE jQuery help

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

I'm trying to get some textarea formatting going on my site using TinyMCE... I'm a little new to integrating this kind of thing and could use some help.

I'm using their jQuery plugin 3.4.x found [here](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php).

I can't seem to get any kind of effect on my textareas! They still look like the regular textareas from before integrating this code. I'm following [this tutorial](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/jQuery_Plugin).

Here is the script I use which is in my header (the `script_url` is correct):

```
<script src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
       theme : "simple"
    });
  });
</script>
```

And my textarea:

```
<textarea name="text" class="tinymce"></textarea>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't given us enough to work with. Show us more code.

Comment: @Incognito Sorry, I felt that this is enough relevant code. I'm not quite sure what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you link us to a version of the page? 
You might not be setting up the directory correctly, including scripts in the wrong order... there's many possibilities here. What error is being thrown?

Comment: Console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce'`. I link to the version I use in my OP.

Comment: Are you sure you've installed it correctly on your local domain?

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using jQuery, make sure you're implementing jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
           script_url : 'tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
           theme : "simple"
        });
      });
</script>
```

### Edit #1

Try loading TinyMCE directly to be assured that there are no issues with loading the file:

```
<script src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
```

Make sure this is loaded BEFORE `$(document).ready()` but after loading jQuery.  Then, omit the `script_url` parameter for `$.tinymce()`.

### Edit #2

There is also a possibility that there is an error with jQuery, or another script on the page. If in Safari or Chrome, right click and select `Inspect Element` to check out the JS console for errors.

### Edit #3

Double-check that you have not mistyped the URL of the `tiny_mce` script, and that it is loading correctly (clear your cache!) in the browser. Also, *if you are using another Javascript framework simultaneously*, make sure you run `jQuery.noConflict()` to see if that is the issue.

### Edit #4! I think I found the issue!

Someone who runs a blog evidently had the exact issue as you did. His solution was to **completely load and initialize `tiny_mce.js`** *before* loading jQuery. Here's [a link to the post](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2007/09/12/how-to-get-jquery-and-tinymce-to-work/), so you can see how he did it.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested... thank you for your response. And yes, this is in my header, however, this did not fix the problem. How do I load it directly?

Comment: thanks again, I updated my  post... that however did not fix the problem yet! No change.

Comment: aha! `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tinymce'`

Comment: That would do it! :) What this means is that for some reason, the TinyMCE jQuery plugin isn't being loaded. In the `Inspect Element` dialog, under `Network`, do you see the TinyMCE JS file?

Comment: I see the following being loaded: jquery.js, jqueryui.js, jquery.tinymce.js, tiny_mce.js. These are all returning status 304 as well.

Comment: Ah- so I know, what is the difference between `jquery.tinymce.js` and `tiny_mce.js`? Because `jquery.tinymce.js` is the plugin, and that's what needs to be loaded before the script. I thought that `tiny_mce.js` was the plugin before.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it just came with the jQuery plugin I downloaded from tinyMCE

Comment: Just updated my answer, check out Edit #3. Could you post in your question the `<head>` section of your document?

Comment: Ah, there you go. Haha, well even if we did spend an hour trying to fix it, at least we got a solution!